# How to make my emulator shows up outside of my android studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

Recently, I updated my android studio to bumblebee version, and when I run my codes, I realized that my emulator are shown inside of my android studio instead of creating a new window for the emulator.  [you can see what I mean, here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwvPD.png)

does anybody knows how to fix this? I already tried to change the settings but nothing is changed. should I reverse the update?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, to resolve it do the following:

In Android Studio: click on
File,
Settings,
Click on the Tools dropdown,
Emulator,
uncheck the "Launch in a tool Window" box

[Settings with Launch in a tool window checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GXJZ.png)